# How to create a hotkey for typing specific lines of code

Tags: editor

I find myself typing the same things over and over again when I code.  Take an easy example of a HTML comment:

```
<!-- -->
```

Instead of typing out the above characters to make an HTML comment each time, is it possible to set up my own personal hotkeys to have an editor automatically remember "`<!-- -->`" so that I can recall it at the press of a button/hotkey?  Do most editors have a tool that does this or is there a specific editor or piece of software that can do this?

I'm sure someone has asked this before but I frankly did not know the name of what I am asking about, so I failed at the search.

Comment: A decent code editor will have this functionality, but it will be editor specific.

Comment: If you are using Sublime Text (among a lot of other editors), you can use the Ctrl + / shortcut for comments, check the documentation for the code editor you are using. What is it btw ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 and Notepad++ on Windows, and currently learning emacs on Ubuntu